# msdeploy 401 unauthorized error while msbuild works with same credentials

Tags: authentication, msbuild, continuous-integration, msdeploy

I am trying to deploy a website, initially I had the following command line

```
MSBuild.exe PortalWeb.sln
    /t:Rebuild
    /p:DeployOnBuild=True
    /p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish
    /p:MSDeployServiceURL=https://wwwt.mycompany.ru:8172/msdeploy.axd
    /p:DeployIISAppPath="Portal/test"
    /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=False
    /p:MsDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC
    /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True
    /p:UserName=DeployUser
    /p:Password=123pwd123
    /p:Configuration="Testing Env"
```

Now I am using TFS build server and try to use a web step that generates the following command

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe"
    -verb:sync
    -source:package='PortalWeb.zip'
    -dest:auto,computerName='https://wwwt.mycompany.ru:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=Portal/test',userName='DeployUser',password='123pwd123',authType='WMSVC',includeAcls='False'
    -allowUntrusted
```

And this command fails with 401 Unathorized error:

```
2017-06-06T16:00:12.7928227Z ##[error]System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Error Code: ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED

2017-06-06T16:00:12.7928227Z ##[error]System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: More Information: Connected to the remote computer ("wwwt.mycompany.ru") using the Web Management Service, but could not authorize. Make sure that you are using the correct user name and password, that the site you are connecting to exists, and that the creden

2017-06-06T16:00:12.7928227Z ##[error]System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: tials represent a user who has permissions to access the site.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED.

2017-06-06T16:00:12.7928227Z Error: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

2017-06-06T16:00:12.7928227Z Error count: 1.
```

Why one command works with these credentials and the other one fails?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the service account of the agent has the needed permission to deploy the website.

But a better way is to create a artifact package in your build process. That's means build and publish your package to a drop folder or inside the tfs.

After that you can deploy your site with release management. There are a lot of benefits if you do this practice.